# Mocking class method with pytest-mock returns error

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I'm trying to mock a class method with pytest-mock. I have the code below in a single file, and when the test is run I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RealClass'` in the `patch` function. How to make this work?

```
class RealClass:
    def some_function():
        return 'real'
    
def function_to_test():
    x = RealClass()
    return x.some_function()

def test_the_function(mocker):

    mock_function = mocker.patch('RealClass.some_function')
    mock_function.return_value = 'mocked'

    ret = function_to_test()
    assert ret == 'mocked'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case since you are patching the class that is present within the test file itself you would use [`mocker.patch.object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object).

```
mock_function = mocker.patch.object(RealClass, 'some_function')
```

---

```
collected 1 item                                                               

tests/test_grab.py::test_the_function PASSED                             [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 0.03s ===============================
```